# How to omit duplicate consecutive chars in a string without using extra space?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I was asked this question by a big company. To my knowledge strings in JS are immutable. Hence, I can't do that. I was wondering if I am missing something. The interview was adamant not to create another var (string, array) and do it in-place.

input: `'harry'`

output: `'hary'`

I had to apologize and insist that I must create an array out of it and do the operations on it or create another empty string and push wanted chars to it.

Did I ruin my interview?

Comment: They are asking for an impossibility.

Comment: That company is a company that has a few of the most famous programming languages (came up with them.) I am surprised they would ask such a question. Perhaps they aren't familiar with JS.

Comment: Maybe they really meant to avoid temporary variables and values? You could perform solve the task by using string replacement with a regular expression. At least in user land that would be a single operation with temp variables/values.